# SQL Server Agent Job

Tags: sql, sql-server, powershell

I have a powershell script that finds the latest SQL backup from a mapped drive Z to a secondary hard drive on the server named J.

```
gci "Z:\company\FULL" | select -last 1 | Copy-Item -destination
    "J:\company\Backup.bak"
```

The script runs fine if I run it from powershell. But when I add it to the SQL Server Agent job, I get an error:

> Invalid Path "J:\company\Backup.bak".

I have made sure that SQL Server Agent account has access to both file locations, but I still get the error.

Comment: Can you use a UNC path instead of a mapped drive? As long as the account has access that should still work.

Comment: I could have worded the drive situation better. Z is the network drive which appears to work properly. It is the J drive that throws the error. That is a second hard drive installed on the server. Not sure how to put the UNC path for that one.

Comment: I updated my powershell script to this: 'gci "Z:\company\FULL" | select -last 1 | Copy-Item -destination "Microsoft.PowerShell.Core\FileSystem::J:\company\Backup.bak"' which will run in PowerShell, but throws the same invalid path error in SQL Agent Job.\

Comment: I created a CmdExec job step that called C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe J:\dbmovescript\Single_backup_move.ps1 but then it threw an invalid path for the Z network drive.

Comment: sorry, the previous comment was incorrect. The error was actually Access Denied.

Answer (score 0):

You need to grant the account that runs the SQL Agent Service, permissions to access the company folder J: drive. Based on your comments it currently this account currently doesn't currently have access.